# Is del or pop preferred when removing elements from dicts

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm relatively new to Python, and was wondering if there is any reason to prefer one of these methods over the other when removing elements from a `dict`?

**A) Using `del`**

```
# d is a dict, k is a key
if k in d:
   del d[k]
```

**B) Using `pop`**

```
d.pop(k, None)
```

My first thought was that approach (A) needs to do two look-ups - once in the `if` statement, and again in the implementation of `del`, which would make it slightly slower than `pop`, which only needs one look-up. A colleague then pointed out that `del` may yet have the edge, because it is a keyword, and may therefore potentially be better optimised, whereas `pop` is a method that can be replaced by end users (not sure if this is really a factor, but he does have far more experience at writing Python code).

I wrote a few test snippets to compare performance. It looks like `del` has the edge (I've appended the snippets if anyone cares to try them out or comment on correctness).

So, this brings me back to the question: Other than a marginal performance gain, is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Here are the snippets to test performance:

## Naive test

```
import timeit
print 'in:   ', timeit.Timer(stmt='42 in d', setup='d = dict.fromkeys(range(100000))').timeit()
print 'pop:  ', timeit.Timer(stmt='d.pop(42,None)', setup='d = dict.fromkeys(range(100000))').timeit()
print 'del:  ', timeit.Timer(stmt='if 42 in d:\n    del d[42]', setup='d = dict.fromkeys(range(100000))').timeit()
```

This outputs

```
in:    0.0521960258484
pop:   0.172810077667
del:   0.0660231113434
```

So that was a curious result. I would have expected `pop` to be roughly on par with `in`, but it's more than three times as expensive. Another surprise was that `del` was only slightly slower than `in`, until I realized that the dictionary from the setup statement in the `timeit` class remains the same instance, so only the first call will hit the `del` statements, as all others won't pass the `if` statement.

## Slightly less naive test

So I wrote a longer profiling snippet in an attempt to try to avoid this. I runs several `timeit` runs with some randomised key selections and tries to ensure that we'll mostly hit the `if` statement and the `del` statement (so we're not working with the same dictionary instance all the time):

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

import timeit

# Number of times to repeat fresh setup before doing timeit runs
repeat_num=100
# Number of timeit runs per setup
number=1000
# Size of dictionary for runs (smaller)
small_size=10000
# Size of dictionary for timeit runs (larger)
large_size=1000000
# Switches garbage collection on if True
collect_garbage = False

setup_stmt = """
import random
d = dict.fromkeys(range(%(dict_size)i))
# key, randomly chosen
k = random.randint(0,%(dict_size)i - 1)
%(garbage)s
"""

in_stmt = """
k in d
%(incr_k)s
""" % {'incr_k' : 'k = (k + 1) %% %(dict_size)i' if number > 1 else ''}

pop_stmt = """
d.pop(k, None)
%(incr_k)s
""" % {'incr_k' : 'k = (k + 1) %% %(dict_size)i' if number > 1 else ''}


del_stmt = """
if k in d:
    del d[k]
%(incr_k)s
""" % {'incr_k' : 'k = (k + 1) %% %(dict_size)i' if number > 1 else ''}

# Results for smaller dictionary size
print \
"""SETUP:
   repeats        : %(repeats)s
   runs per repeat: %(number)s
   garbage collect: %(garbage)s""" \
       % {'repeats' : repeat_num,
          'number'  : number,
          'garbage' : 'yes' if collect_garbage else 'no'}
print "SMALL:"
small_setup_stmt = setup_stmt % \
    {'dict_size' : small_size,
     'garbage' : 'gc.enable()' if collect_garbage else ''}
times = timeit.Timer(stmt=in_stmt % {'dict_size' : small_size},
    setup=small_setup_stmt).repeat(repeat=repeat_num,number=number)
print "    in:  ", sum(times)/len(times)
times = timeit.Timer(stmt=pop_stmt % {'dict_size' : small_size},
    setup=small_setup_stmt).repeat(repeat=repeat_num,number=number)
print "    pop: ", sum(times)/len(times)
times = timeit.Timer(stmt=del_stmt % {'dict_size' : small_size},
    setup=small_setup_stmt).repeat(repeat=repeat_num,number=number)
print "    del: ", sum(times)/len(times)

# Results for larger dictionary size
print "LARGE:"
large_setup_stmt = setup_stmt % \
    {'dict_size' : large_size,
     'garbage' : 'gc.enable()' if collect_garbage else ''}
times = timeit.Timer(stmt=in_stmt  % {'dict_size' : large_size},
    setup=large_setup_stmt).repeat(repeat=repeat_num,number=number)
print "    in:  ", sum(times)/len(times)
times = timeit.Timer(stmt=pop_stmt  % {'dict_size' : large_size},
    setup=large_setup_stmt).repeat(repeat=repeat_num,number=number)
print "    pop: ", sum(times)/len(times)
times = timeit.Timer(stmt=del_stmt  % {'dict_size' : large_size},
    setup=large_setup_stmt).repeat(repeat=repeat_num,number=number)
print "    del: ", sum(times)/len(times)
```

Doing 100 setups, each with 1000 runs each, prints the following:

```
SETUP:
   repeats        : 100
   runs per repeat: 1000
   garbage collect: no
SMALL:
    in:   0.00020430803299
    pop:  0.000313355922699
    del:  0.000262062549591
LARGE:
    in:   0.000201721191406
    pop:  0.000328607559204
    del:  0.00027587890625
```

I'm new to using `timeit`, so it's possible that this is a flawed test, but it does seem to indicate that `del` has a small advantage in terms of performance.

One thing I did learn from this exercise the hard way is that Python dictionaries are hash maps, so the size of the dictionary doesn't affect the look-up time as much as it would a C++ `std::map`, for example (constant time vs O(log(n))-ish). Oh well. Live and learn.

Comment: the `pop` is slower for 2 reasons: it needs to return a value, and it needs a name lookup for the `pop` name for each access.

Comment: In your first example you have `del k` (which has no effect on `d`) instead of `del d[k]`.

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong - Good spot. Fixed it up - thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would not worry about the performance differences unless you have specific reason to believe that they are causing meaningful slowdowns in your program, which is unlikely.

The real reason you might choose to use `del` vs `pop` is because they have different behaviors.  `pop` returns the value for the popped key, so you would use `pop` if you want to do something with that value at the same time as you remove it.  If you don't need to do anything with the value, but just want to remove the item, use `del`.